# Powershell replace text in file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to script out replacing text in a text file. I want to replace

```
SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/file.cer"
```

with

```
SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/NewFile.cer"
```

I have written:

```
(Get-Content C:\foler\location\httpd-ssl.conf) -replace ('[SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/file.cer"]', 'SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/NewFile.cer"') | Set-Content C:\foler\location\httpd-ssl.conf
```

This is replacing the entire httpd-ssl.conf with SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/NewFile.cer"

help

Comment: just use copy-item

Answer (score 0):

-replace uses regex, you have to escape chars with a special meaning in a regex.
And what are the square brackets in the pattern for?

```
$Search = [RegEx]::escape('SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/file.cer"')
$Replace= 'SSLCertificateFile "D:/folder/location/NewFile.cer"'
$File =  'C:\foler\location\httpd-ssl.conf'
(Get-Content $File) -replace $Search,$Replace|
 Set-Content $File
```